# How do you pass a string literal in from a settings file in C#

Tags: c#, string, settings, app-config, literals

I want to create a configuration setting to pass in a string to my application. The string is based on some text from a web page which is the reason I need to allow for it to be changed from within a config file.

The string I want to pass in is

a)

```
Forecast Summary:</b> 
    <span class="phrase">
```

And the format of the string literal that works when I use it to search the page is

b)

```
string myString = "Forecast Summary:</b> \n        <span class=\"phrase\">";
```

the problem is that the passed in string (by pasting the text in (a) above into the App Settings screen ) comes through in the format

c)

```
"Forecast Summary:</b> \r\n        <span class=\"phrase\">"
```

(which has a carriage return inserted)

Is there a way to enter the string in the App.Config as the "exact" string literal

Comment: How do you know it comes through?  The quick watch window shows escape characters.

Comment: I am trying to use string.IndexOf(myString) to locate the string on a page. Looking at the value of myString, it contains the extra carriage return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) or XML Escape codes.

```
<myxml>
    <record>
        <![CDATA[
        Line 1 <br />
        Line 2 <br />
        Line 3 <br />
        ]]>
    </record>
</myxml>
```

see here for more info about [XML Escaping](http://tntluoma.com/sidebars/codes/)

for more info see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222367/escape-quote-character-in-xml) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 0):

I first solved it by entering XML Encoded characters directly into the App.Config.

```
<setting name="DataExtractFrom" serializeAs="String">
     <value>Forecast Summary:&lt;/b&gt; &#10;        &lt;span class="phrase"&gt;</value>
</setting>
```

(Previously I had pasted it into the Settings screen for the project which must add the extra carriage return)

then

As pylover suggested above, it works if I edit the App.Config file using CDATA format ..

```
<setting name="DataExtractFrom" serializeAs="String">
   <value><![CDATA[Forecast Summary:</b> \n        <span class=\"phrase\">]]></value>
</setting>
```

This looks cleaner in the config file so I ended up using that format.