# How to use double quotes in xml?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I use QT's `QDomDocument`. There is a problem when using [`QDomDocument::setContent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#setContent), the compiler complains at this line:

`< field regexp = "text".+"text" >`

I tried so:

- `< field regexp = "text"".+""text" >`
- `< field regexp = "text'"'.+'"'text" >`
- `< field regexp = "text\".+\"text" >`

Comment: Why don't you just use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (variant 6 on that page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML attribute values can be delimited by `'`, which is useful when the attribute value must contain a `"`.

So, if the attribute value in intended to be, say, `text".+"text`, use:

```
<field regexp='text".+"text'>
```

Alternatively, `&quot;` can be used for `"`.

```
<field regexp="text&quot;.+&quot;text">
```

**See also:**

- [When to escape double quote in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534409/290085)
- [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)

Comment: Or just use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I'd only addressed the XML well-formedness concerns.  Thanks for adding the suggestion regarding string formation for the C++ function argument, which indeed has to be satisfied first.