# How to escape XPath quotes "" with C#

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to scrape Pinterest using XPath and HTMLAgilityPack, but XPath writes `""` (`//*(@id="XX"`) to represent the id attribute value, so in C# the strings are split and I get a syntax error. (`"["@id="XX(error)"]"`) What should I do?

Comment: You need to provide a sample of the content you want to scrape, as well as the C# source that's not behaving. Otherwise, we're forced to guess at how you're doing it, in which I'd suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

First, fix your XPath syntax error: Change `//*(@id="XX"` to `//*[@id="XX"]`.

Then, to represent `//*[@id="XX"]` as a C# string, use either C# escaping or XPath alternative attribute value delimiters.

### C# escaping

Escape the `"` in C# via `\"`

```
"//*[@id=\"XX\"]"
```

or via verbatim string literal syntax

```
@"//*[@id=""XX""]"
```

### XPath alternative attribute value delimiters

Use `'` as the attribute value delimiter, which both XML and XPath allow:

```
"//*[@id='XX']"
```

### See also

- [Escape double quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14480724/290085) (C#)
- [Escape double quote character in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1222367/290085) (XML and XPath)