# C# App.config retrieve System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable - Missing whitespace required

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to pass a System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("String") from Jenkins to my app.config file and im getting a 'missing Whitespace' error. I think its because im calling a string within a string? I can't seem to find a way to escape it however

```
<add key="Env_Custom-TestUrl" value="System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BaseURL")" />
```

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Check if variable exists using cmd.exe >SET  SET will give a list of all variables.

Comment: Regardless whether it exists or not, if the syntax isn't right it won't be able to access it. Its a Jenkins variable so not available in the environment

Comment: GetEnvironmentVariable() will only work if it is a windows variable.  So it needs to be seen in cmd.exe.

Comment: It does work if you assign GetEnvironmentVariable() to a variable and call that. That is my workaround

Comment: Read you comment again start with "Regardless".  You said "exist or not".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222367/escape-double-quote-character-in-xml